# PDF bookmarks for thmtools' theorems

Tags: theorems, bookmarks, thmtools

I would like to add PDF bookmarks for some classes of theorems declared using `thmtools` and I couldn't find a beautiful way to do it so far.

The best idea I have been able to come up with was to add `\pdfbookmark` commands to the `postheadhook` key of `\declaretheorem`. But for this to work I have to get a unique identifier for each theorem, presumbably using an internal command from `thmtools` and I have not been able to figure out how.

This is most certainly possible, since `thmtools` used with `hyperref` is able to create hyperlinks to the theorems in `\listoftheorems`, so there could lie another way to do what I want, but I can't find it.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem[title=Theorem,postheadhook={\pdfbookmark{a_name}{some_identifier}}]{theo}
\begin{document}
\begin{theo}
    Continuous maps map quasi-compact sets to quasi-compact sets.
\end{theo}
\newpage
\begin{theo}[Tykhonov]
    Cartesian products of compact spaces are compact for the product topology.
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Here, PDF bookmarks are correctly created, but of course have all the same name and point to the first theorem.

Comment: How about you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) containing your current usage so the community has something to play with?

Comment: If you want to apply it to specific classes of theorems, say `definition`, you could use something like `uidDefinition\theHdefinition` as your unique identifier. `\theHdefinition` is the expandable representation of the theorem number as used by hyperref. It's not guaranteed to be unique, but pretty much the best shot you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example uses package `bookmark` for finer control of the bookmark.
It uses the anchor `hyperref` sets for the theorem (`\@currentHref`). And the title is stored in `\@currentlabelname` by package `nameref` (loaded by `hyperref`). The bookmark is added as child to the current bookmark and the bookmark level is not changed afterwards.

Package `thmtools` stores the theorem title name in `\thmt@thmname` (thanks Evpok) and the environment/counter name in `\thmt@envname`. That allows the definition of `\theorembookmark` for use in key `postheadhook` of `\declaretheorem`. `\theorembookmark` gets its data from the internal macros above.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\theorembookmark}{%
  \bookmark[
    dest=\@currentHref,
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
  ]{%
    \thmt@thmname\space\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname
    \ifx\@currentlabelname\@empty
    \else
      \space(\@currentlabelname)%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[title=Theorem, postheadhook=\theorembookmark]{theo}
\declaretheorem[title=Lemma,   postheadhook=\theorembookmark]{lemma}

\begin{document}
\section{Section with unnamed theorem}
\begin{theo}
    Continuous maps map quasi-compact sets to quasi-compact sets.
\end{theo}
\begin{lemma}
    Unnamed lemma.
\end{lemma}
\newpage
\subsection{Subsection with named theorem}
\begin{theo}[Tykhonov]
    Cartesian products of compact spaces are compact for the product
 topology.
\end{theo}
\subsection{Next subsection with named lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Emma]
    Named lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Using the name for the list of theorems

Macro `\thmt@shortoptarg` contains the name for the list of theorems. It is set to the full name if the optional argument is not given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\theorembookmark}{%
  \bookmark[
    dest=\@currentHref,
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
  ]{%
    \thmt@thmname\space\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname
    \ifx\thmt@shortoptarg\@empty
    \else
      \space(\thmt@shortoptarg)%
    \fi
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[title=Theorem, postheadhook=\theorembookmark]{theo}
\declaretheorem[title=Lemma,   postheadhook=\theorembookmark]{lemma}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems 

\section{Section with unnamed theorem}
\begin{theo}
    Continuous maps map quasi-compact sets to quasi-compact sets.
\end{theo}
\begin{lemma}
    Unnamed lemma.
\end{lemma}
\newpage   
\subsection{Subsection with named theorem}
\begin{theo}[Tykhonov]
    Cartesian products of compact spaces are compact for the product
 topology.
\end{theo}
\subsection{Next subsection with named lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Emma]
    Named lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[{name=[LoT-Name]{Doc-Name}}]
    Named lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: There seem to be no need to define `\theoremname`, you can use `\thmt@thmname` for that.

Comment: @Evpok: Thanks, that allows me together with `\thmt@envname` to put the bookmark code in macro `\theorembookmark`, see the edited question.

Comment: So our answers are essentially the same :) let's keep it that way.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this solution, so the bookmarks contain the same strings as in `\listoftheorems`, i.e. the optional name of the theorem – if present – is used? That would be the ideal solution for me `:-)`

Comment: @JBantje The bookmarks already contain the theorem type name (`title`) and  the optional name of the theorem instance.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That's not what I meant: `\begin{lemma}[{name=[for list of theorems]{optional name in document}}] ...` should put `for list of theorems` in the bookmark.

Comment: @JBantje See updated answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This answer is really nice. I struggled to accomplish the following though: without specifying "title=", for instance, \declaretheorem{lemma} prints "Lemma" for the environment \begin{lemma}...\end{lemma} but if you try to add this to your answer, this no longer works. Is there a way to fix this to avoid having to specify the uppercase version of the environment?

Comment: @Math-user The default theorem name uses an internal form of `\MakeUppercase` that is not expandable and breaks, when converted to a bookmark. The purpose of `\MakeUppercase` is to make the first letter of `lemma` uppercase. Thus, the easiest solution is to use `title` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution. Drawing inspiration from [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123466/8547), but not relying on *ad hoc* commands, everything wrapped in a convenient `\thbookmark` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thlabel}[1]{
    \thmt@thmname\space\@nameuse{the#1}
    \ifx\@currentlabelname\@empty
    \else
      \space(\@currentlabelname)%
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\thbookmark}{\bookmark[dest=\@currentHref,rellevel=1,keeplevel,]{\thlabel{\thmt@envname}}}
\makeatother
\declaretheorem[title=Theorem, postheadhook={\thbookmark}]{theo}

\begin{document}
\section{Section with unnamed theorem}
\begin{theo}
    Continuous maps map quasi-compact sets to quasi-compact sets.
\end{theo}
\newpage
\subsection{Subsection with named theorem}
\begin{theo}[Tykhonov]
    Cartesian products of compact spaces are compact for the product
 topology.
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```