# Adding pdf bookmark entries to theorems from shadethm

Tags: theorems, bookmarks

Similarily to [the same question asked for `thmtools`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123447/pdf-bookmarks-for-thmtools-theorems), I would like to automatically add pdfbookmark entries for each theorem.

The issue is that I can't really re-write the whole preamble and move away from shadethm (I'm filling out handouts in class that my prof. provides LaTeX sources for).

The handouts call shortcuts to `\begin`/`\end` commands defined as such:

```tex
\newshadetheorem{_prop}{Proposition}
\newshadetheorem{_cor}{Corollaire}
\newcommand{\pro}{\begin{_prop}}
\newcommand{\orp}{\end{_prop}}
\newcommand{\col}{\begin{_cor}}
\newcommand{\loc}{\end{_cor}}
```

And `\pro`/`\orp` and others for corollaries, theorems, definitions, etc. are used throughout the document. I can modify the preamble, I just need it to stay compatible with LaTeX documents written without my changes.

It seems like the two only plausible solutions are:

- Customizing shade theorems by adding hooks, which, according to [shadethm's documentation](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/shadethm/shadethm-doc.pdf), seems impossible
- Adding calls to `\belowpdfbookmark` (from the *hyperref* package) in `\pro`, `\col` and similar, but, in that case:

  - How do I get the current shade theorem's name and counter (to achieve a result indentical to [this answer to an identical question for *thmtools*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123466)) ?